# php: performing math inside of an "echo". also passing variable name to a function

Tags: php, function, math, operation

I'm building a table (tho not using `<table>`) and populating it with data from mysql. I have the following code to build the "table":

```
$NYC = // data from mysql, working fine
$NYC_min = 300;
switch($cou_mun){
    case "New York":
        $NYC++;
        break;
    //etc
}

function cityMinMet($city){
    $city_min= "$city" . "_min";
    if($city>$city_min){return "yes";}
    else{return "no";};
}

echo "<h3>Table 6: Recruitment by target area</h3>";
echo "<ul>\n<li><span>Target Area</span><span>Number Recruited</span><span>Amount under minimum</span><span>Minimum</span><span>Minimum met?</span></li>";
echo "<li><span>12 Jurisdictions with Highest AIDS Prevalance</span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></li>";
echo "<li><span>New York</span><span>$NYC</span><span>" . $NYC_min-$NYC . "</span><span>$NYC_min</span><span>"; cityMinMet('$NYC'); echo "</span></li>";
```

I encounter a problem with `" . $NYC_min-$NYC . "`: it breaks the row (the row gets interpreted as ending just before `" . $NYC_min-$NYC . "`. However, if I have `<span>$NYC_min-$NYC</span>` (not as an additional component of the echo), the value of the cell is printed as `300-500` instead of `200`.

Also I'm not sure I've setup my function properly (but this is not breaking the table/row). From `cityMinMet('$NYC')` I want the literal string `$NYC` (and not its value) sent to the function. Inside the function I need to append `_min` to `$NYC` and then call `$NYC_min` and it return with its value.

***EDIT**: I changed the order of `$NYC` and `$NYC_min` in the equation.*

Comment: The way you're calling the function (with single quotes) *will* pass the literal string. Also, if you need the value of `$NYC_min` in function `cityMinMet` then just **pass** the value to the function. Don't make your code jump through variable variable/global hoops.

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate to use `<table>` for tabular data.

Comment: @webbiedave: oh cool thanks! how else do I pass the value of $NYC_min to the function without doing it this way?

Comment: @Herbert: I want to stylise the table, and `<table>` tags accept almost no css :(

Comment: @jacob: Ah! I see. Some people read articles about not using `<table>` for layout and assume it means "never us `<table>` _anywhere_ for _any_ reason _whatsoever_". Just thought I'd point out that it's okay to use it for it was intended (in case you didn't know). :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap it in parenthesis:

```
" . ($NYC - $NYC_min) . "
```

Comment: You can also use commas with echo: `", $NYC - $NYC_min, "`

Answer (score 2):

For the `" . $NYC-$NYC_min . "`, change to `" . ($NYC-$NYC_min) . "`

To pass the literal string `$NYC` use `"\$NYC"`.  Note, you need to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` here, otherwise it will pass the string literal `\$NYC`

As @webbiedave points out in his comment, passing it as `'$NYC'` should already be sending the string literal `$NYC`

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem: `$NYC - $NYC_min` is being interpreted as a string (subtly cast as such) because you are concatenating it with a string.  You should perform the maths before the echo and store it in a variable which you write in there (clean) or you can put it in brackets so its interpreted before the php parser considers the string concatenation context.

Answer (score 1):

> From cityMinMet('$NYC') I want the literal string $NYC (and not its
>   value) sent to the function.

The way you're calling the function (with single quotes) will pass the literal string.

However, if you need the value of `$NYC_min` in function `cityMinMet` then just pass the value to the function:

```
function cityMinMet($city, $city_min)
{
    if ($city > $city_min) {
        return "yes";
    } else {
        return "no";
    }
}
```

In your calling code do:

```
echo cityMinMet($NYC, $NYC_min);
```

Or you can forgo the function all together and just do:

```
echo ($city > $city_min) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: ahh, gotcha. that last one is pretty cool too! Do you know which one would be more efficient? (I'll be running at least 21 of these).

Comment: If you're doing it numerous times then definitely go with the function. That way if you have to change, say, `'yes'` to `'Y'`, you can do it in just one place.

Comment: btw I ended up condensing everything into a for loop and the functions are called inside it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest to make a quick function to do what you need to do:

```
function calculate($nyc, $nyc_min) {
  return $nyc - $nyc_min;
}
```

then replace what you have with:

```
echo "<li><span>New York</span><span>$NYC</span><span>" . calculate($NYC,$NYC_min) . "</span>...";
```